# Domain foo.bar points 127.0.53.53 -- why?

Tags: dns, localhost

I just noticed today that domain foo.bar resolves to 127.0.53.53 (http://foo.bar, http://whois.domaintools.com/foo.bar)

In my case this ends up on the localhost Apache, but I wonder why the registrant did not simply chose to point to 127.0.0.1? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: http://www.computerworld.com.au/article/539336/icann_seeks_tackle_dns_namespace_collision_risks/

Comment: Belongs on [sf]...and is [a duplicate](http://serverfault.com/q/626612/126632)

Comment: I was connected to a VPN. Once disconnectet all was fine again :FacePalm:

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`127.0.53.53` is a special IP addresses that is used by [ICANN to prevent DNS name collisions with the new gTLDs](https://www.icann.org/namecollision).

In your case the `.bar` gTLD was [delegated](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/delegated-strings) in February. So the `127.0.53.53` is a big hint for people using .bar in their internal setups that the .bar domain name will be used in the global DNS very soon.

If you look closer at the `foo.bar` record you see more information:

```
$ dig foo.bar A +short
127.0.53.53
$ dig foo.bar TXT +short
"Your DNS configuration needs immediate attention see https://icann.org/namecollision"
$ dig foo.bar MX +short
10 your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.bar.
$ dig foo.bar SRV +short
10 10 0 your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.bar.
```

Comment: Who is "we"? 127.0.53.53 was chosen because it makes searching for this issue simple. Also there is no functional difference between 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.53.53.

Comment: Sebastian, TCP/IP stacks won't respond to requests destined for 127.0.53.53, but they will respond to requests destined for 127.0.0.1. That is a big difference. @jrmgx Yes, use a local DNS server like dnsmasq and point your local DNS to 127.0.0.1 and you can resolve *.bar (or anything, really) to whatever you want, including 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @GregSchmit ping 127.0.53.53 ;) Systems respond to everything under 127/8.

Comment: @Sebastian Silly Windows stacks will assign it to localhost (wrongly), but Unix systems (e.g., OS X or FreeBSD) will do the Right Thing. ;) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8A0lXQwAyCiSjZTRFdmNXVNU0U

Comment: @Sebastian And I hope you meant *within* 127.0.0.0/8, not below it. There is an argument that the whole block should loopback from the wording of RFC3330, but most stacks don't (and IMO, shouldn't; think of all the stuff we can do with those IP addresses!).

Comment: I meant every IP in 127/8. At least my Windows 10 responds to any address in 127/8.

Comment: Linux also responds on all IPs in 127/8