# symlinked hosts file ignored by OS X; dev domains redirect to 127.0.53.53

Tags: macos, dns, osx-mavericks, hosts, icann

I'm aware that various domains are now [redirected to 127.0.53.53 by ICANN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662590/domain-foo-bar-points-127-0-53-53-why/25665936#25665936) to alert people to potential current/future name collisions.

However, I assumed any entries in my hosts file, for, for example, a development site running on Vagrant using a `.dev` domain, would still be honoured and have priority.

Currently I've a situation on a Mac (OSX 10.9.5) where most browsers (Safari 7.1.2, Firefox 35, Chrome Canary) are attempting to connect to  127.0.53.53 regardless.  The only way I can get it to work is to change the TLD to something else.

Weirdly in Chrome stable 39.0.2171.95, which is my main browser, the `.dev` hosts file entries  still load OK at present.

I've tried various things, restarting apps, restarting the VM, simplifying the hosts file / looking for errors, flushing the cache – `dscacheutil -flushcache` etc. Hosts entries with other TLDs (or none) still work fine.

Fixable / is there anything I've forgotten?

Comment: that'd depend on what apple did to their dns resolver in osx, and whether any particular app is actually using that resolver. looks like chrome has their own and ignores whatever is being done in osx.

Comment: @MarcB fixed it - my /etc/hosts was a symlink, not a regular file – apparently OSX only checks symlinked versions if the DNS lookup doesn't resolve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason was I had my /etc/hosts file symlinked (to Dropbox) and [having read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6844817/763419), it turns out you must have an ordinary local file if you want to override anything that already has a valid DNS record (which ICANN's 127.0.53.53 is) – if the file is a symlink apparently it doesn't get checked first.

Have verified that removing the symlink makes it work again.  Can't explain why Chrome was different though.

Comment: Ditto this answer; I had to recreate a file at `/etc/hosts` instead of using a symlinked file in my Dropbox. Makes synchronizing hosts files between computers a little more burdensome, but at least my local domains are working correctly again.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer, this was the resolution to my problem as well :) I wonder if this is purely an OSX issue, or if it's just how things are everywhere else.

Comment: @geerlingguy — you might want to try a `/etc/hosts.d`-type solution noted in this answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60554/87040

Comment: You could also use a hard link instead of a symbolic link